# Play music directly from terminal

Tags: virtual-terminal

I need to learn how to play my music directly from terminal. No GUI. The music is in a folder in another drive

Comment: `aplay` is another one that is commandline

Answer (score 1):

You could use ogg123 or mpg123, depending on the file format. They are both in the standard repositories at least on Ubuntu 14.04.

The usage is..

```
ogg123 path
mpg123 path
```

For other alternatives have a look here:
http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/12/10-console-music-players-for-linux/

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of audacious, you can give a go to this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/audtty.1.html

Comment: one other thing you could consider doing, if I understand your problem, is to mount your remote folder to your local file system, so that you can use any player to play the music on the remote drive. See for example sshfs or samba.

Comment: I used the command  vlc -I ncurses

Comment: But the source is empty like: Source:<no current item>

Comment: sorry Evlis those comments are not relevant to the solution I proposed. I cannot help you with vlc.